# Retrieving coefficients of polynomial from DFT using inverse DFT

Tags: fft, discrete-mathematics, dft

I am trying to multiply two polynomials using DFT and I don't know how to get the last bit from the DFT of their multiplication.

So there's p(x) = x - 4, dft -3, i-4, -5, -i-4
And        q(x) = x^2-1, dft 0, -2, 0, -2

degree(pq) = 3

So we get the 4th roots of unity 1, i, -1, -i

dft for pq is 0, 8-2i, 0, 8+2i.

Could someone please tell me how to get the coefficients for pq now from its dft?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to understand is that multiplying two polynomials is the same as [convolving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution) the coefficients.

```
octave:1> p=[0 0 1 -4];
octave:2> q=[0 1 0 -1];
octave:3> conv(p,q)
ans =
    0   0   0   1  -4  -1   4
```

Secondly, understand the conditions under which [circular convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution) is equivalent to linear convolution.

(Also, your DFT coeffs seem to be wrong)

Comment: Why are my DFT coeffs wrong? Do you not just use the roots of unity to calculate the DFT for each polynomial, then do pointwise multiplication and then inverse DFT to get the result? How do you do inverse DFT?